# Set the scale the figure in R

Tags: r, plot, figure

I want to plot a figure by the ratio of xaxis to yaxis as 2 (x/y=2). Here, the ratio refers to the physical lenght of xaxis and yaxis. So the yaxis diplays as half of the xaxis. 
As I know, the figure can be plotted as a square (i.e, x/y=1) by seting the parameter of "pty" as "s". But it is impossible to set the "pty" as a number.
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asp` in the arguments to the plot function or you can save your generic plot using the `png` function, with a specific x and y as defined by the arguments `width` and `height`.

Following you comment, you can work with the `xlim` and `ylim` to ensure the physical dimensions of your plot along the axes. For example, to ensure that the `ylim` is twice the `xlim` you could do the following.

```
xlim=range(mpg$hwy)
ylim = range(mpg$cty) # y is 16

plot(data = mpg, cty~hwy, ylim = c(ylim[1]-16, ylim[2]+16))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe I didn't The asp argument

Comment: You are welcome to upvote the question and/or select it as an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe I didn't express the questions clearly. Here the ratio is the physical length, just as the effect of pty in par(). The asp argument can not control the physical length ratio. The arguments width and height are not very exact to set the axises, especially for multiple plots.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want... You mean you want to make sure that the physical limits of the plot are twice as long in one direction as the other?

Comment: Maybe you can try the argument of pty as "s" in par() to plot a figure. For instance, 
> par(pty="s")
> plot(1.1). 
Then, you can drag the plot panel to check the figure.

Comment: That code just plots a single point at 1.1 with a square aspect ratio. That is not really going to help you, I think.